# How do you pass JSON data from your views to your index template in Flask?

Tags: json, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to send JSON data from views to index template in Flask, to use as part of JavaScript's D3 library (attempting to visualize companies and their acquisitions).

In views.py, I'm querying my PostgreSQL database (through SQLAlchemy) to retrieve all companies and their respective acquisitions:

```
def index(root=None):
    acq = models.Company.query.all()
    #query the database which is defined in models.py
    root = {}
    for u in acq:
       acqui = json.dumps(list(u.aq))
       # u.aq represents each companies' acquisitions
       root [u.name] = acqui 
    return render_template('index.html', root=root)
```

root is a dictionary where they keys are the company names and the values are their acquisitions. I'm trying to pass that on as a variable to 'index.html'

In index.html, in the  tags where my JavaScript code lies, I'm trying to retrieve root:

```
root = '{{root}}';
console.log(typeof(root));
console.log(root);
```

It's logging 'root' as a string type and printing them out in this format:

```
{u&#39;Google&#39;: &#39;[&#34;Nest Labs&#34;, &#34;Acquisition&#34;, &#34;Acquisition&#34;, &#34;Waze&#34;, &#34;Acquisition&#34;, &#34;Acquisition&#34;, &#34;Acquisition&#34;, &#34;Keyhole Inc.&#34;, &#34;Titan Aerospace&#34 ...
```

How would I pass the 'root' dictionary as a JSON object in order to retrieve it appropriately in my JavaScript code in index.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't want to `json.dumps` the data - instead, pass all the data to the template as-is:

```
root = {u.name: list(u.aq) for u in acq}
return render_template('index.html', root=root)
```

Then, in your JavaScript block, convert the data to JSON there all in one go by using the [`tojson`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#module-flask.json) filter:

```
var root = {{ root | tojson }};
console.log(typeof root);
console.log(root);
```

Comment: TypeError: [u'Nest Labs', u'Motorola Mobility', u'Admeld', u'PostRank', u'modu', u'TalkBin', u'PushLife', u'BeatThatQuote.com', u'zynamics', u'SayNow', u'fflick', u'eBook Technologies', u'Zetawire', u'Widevine Technologies', u'Phonetic Arts', u'Ruba', u'Freebase', u'BlindType', u'Plannr', u'Quiksee', u'MentorWave Technologies', u'SocialDeck', u'Angstro', u'Like.com', u'Jambool', u'Slide', u'Instantiations', u'Metaweb Technologies', u'ITA Software', u'GrandCentral'......] is not JSON serializable

Comment: That was because I had to convert the dict's 'values' to lists root = {u.name: list(u.aq) for u in acq}. After that and your changes, I still see 'root' as a string and the same format as it was before.

Comment: I modified root to be: var root = '{{ root | tojson | safe }}' but now I'm getting a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier " error because there are single quotes in root. How would I fix that?

Comment: It seems like it's doing that because it's still seeing root as a string. Why is it being passed as a JSON string and not a JSON object?

Comment: You don't want to quote `{{ root | tojson }}` - if you do that you are telling JavaScript that there is a string here - but what you actually want is a JavaScript object.  Change `var root = '{{ root | tojson | safe }}'` to `var root = {{ root | tojson | safe }};` (note the lack of quotes).